# Passar variavel no *ngIf

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

eu tenho um variável no meu `input.component.ts` chamada `validacaoExterna`, que recebe uma string de quem for utilizá-la..

```
@Input() validacaoExterna: string;
```

No meu `input.component.html` eu tenho um ***ngIf** que utiliza essa variável

```
*ngIf="input.errors."{{validacaoExterna}}" && (input.dirty || input.touched)"
```

Porém desse modo não está funcionando. Gostaria de saber como posso utilizar essa variável dentro desse ***ngIf**, sendo que ele pega o valor de erro no input + essa variável `input.erro.validacaoExterna`

Comment: tenta assim *ngIf="input.errors[validacaoExterna] && (input.dirty || input.touched)"

Comment: O certo e vc salvar essa expressao numa variavel e fazer *ngIf="variavel" tem como vc mostrar mais codigo pra eu tentar enteder o contexto

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Eduardo, pode marcar como resposta que dou o OK aqui! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 *ngIf="input.errors[validacaoExterna] && (input.dirty || input.touched)"
```